# Wizard for the customers to configure the product before buying

Tags: nopcommerce

I need to let the users to configure the products, by selecting some options, uploading an image or inserting a text, before they add the selected product to the cart.

I need something like a wizard. For example

1. Select a product from the store
2. Select or upload an image to print on it
3. Enter a text to print on it
4. Select one of the available packages
5. Preview the final product
6. Add prodcut to the cart

What is the best way to do this? Is it possible to write a plugin (without changing the core)?